# How to remove characters from a string, except those in a list

Tags: c#, regex, list, replace, character

This is my string value:

```
string str = "32 ab d32";
```

And this list is my allowed characters:

```
var allowedCharacters = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "2", " " };
```

I want it to become:

```
str == " 2 ab   2";
```

I would like to replace any character that is not in the allowed character list,  with an empty space.

Comment: @des thanks i forget codeing :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex? Regex may be overkill for what you're trying to accomplish.

Here's another variation without regex (modified your `lstAllowedCharacters` to actually be an enumerable of **characters** and not strings [as the variable name implies]):

```
String original = "32 ab d32";
Char replacementChar = ' ';
IEnumerable<Char> allowedChars = new[]{ 'a', 'b', 'c', '2', ' ' };

String result = new String(
  original.Select(x => !allowedChars.Contains(x) ? replacementChar : x).ToArray()
);
```

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: Depends on implementation. A list of strings could fail (as Tim's is really only comparing character-for-character even though strings are accepted). They both do the same, I just make it more explicit what's being compared.

Answer (score 5):

Without regex:

```
IEnumerable<Char> allowed = srVariable
    .Select(c => lstAllowedCharacters.Contains(c.ToString()) ? c : ' ');
string result = new string(allowed.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string srVariable = "32 ab d32";
List<string> lstAllowedCharacters = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c", "2", " " };

srVariable = Regex.Replace(srVariable, "[^" + Regex.Escape(string.Join("", lstAllowedCharacters) + "]"), delegate(Match m)
{
    if (!m.Success) { return m.Value; }
    return " ";
});

Console.WriteLine(srVariable);
```

Comment: nope i want it to replace characters not in the predefined list not define them as you showed.

Comment: I've tweaked my answer, however, note the negating `^` character in the pattern. The result does return `" 2 ab   2"` that you asked for.

Comment: May want to call [`Regex.Escape()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) before inserting in to the `Regex.Replace` call to avoid any invalid characters. resulting in: `Regex.Replace(srVariable, String.Format("[^{0}]", Regex.Escape(String.Join(String.Empty, lstAllowedCharacters))))`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple but performant foreach solution:

```
Hashset<char> lstAllowedCharacters = new Hashset<char>{'a','b','c','2',' '};

var resultStrBuilder = new StringBuilder(srVariable.Length);

foreach (char c in srVariable) 
{
    if (lstAllowedCharacters.Contains(c))
    {
        resultStrBuilder.Append(c);
    }
    else
    {
        resultStrBuilder.Append(" ");
    }
}

srVariable = resultStrBuilder.ToString();
```